# Do I really need to use virtualenv with Django?

Tags: python, django, vagrant, virtualenv

This may well stink of newbie but...

I'm working on my first Django project, and am reading a lot that using `virtualenv` is considered Best Practice.  I understand that `virtualenv` sandboxes all my python dependencies but I just don't know if this is necessary if I'm working in sandboxed VM's anyway?  I'm developing in Vagrant, and won't be using these VM's for anything else, and I'll be deploying to a VM server that will only have this Django project on it. Is it possible that in the future further Django apps in this project will require different dependencies and so need to be in different `virtualenv`'s? (Not sure if it works like that tbh?)

Am I just showing my inexperience and shortsightedness?

Comment: Suppose you've got an old project which you've built using `Django 1.5`. But for your new project, you'd like to use `Django 1.8`. If you install `v1.8`, your old project will not be compatible with the new version. So what is the safe way to do it? You'd create a *virtual environment* for your new project and install `v1.8` in it. This way you can use both the versions simultaneously.

Comment: Yeah, I get this, makes perfect sense.  What I'm saying though, is that I'm not ever going to have more than one project per VM.  Therefore is there any reason to use `virtualenv` on top of the VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have any knowledge on Vagrant but I use virtualenvs for my Django projects. I would recommend it for anyone.

With that said, if you're only going to be using one Django project on a virtual machine you don't *need* to use a virtualenv. I haven't come across a situation where apps in the same project have conflicting dependencies. This could be a problem if you have multiple projects on the same machine however.

Answer (score 5):

I would always recommend you use a virtualenv as a matter of course. There is almost no overhead in doing so, and it just makes things easier. In conjunction with virtualenvwrapper you can easily just type `workon myproject` to activate and cd to your virtualenv in one go. You avoid any issues with having to use `sudo` to install things, as well as any possible version incompatibilities with system-installed packages. There's just no reason not to, really.

Comment: Yeah virtualenvwrapper is great, I use it when I use virtualenv. OK, I can see it would be good to separate the project from the system.  It just feels a little bit 'just in case' and using it because it's there.  I guess maybe I have the naivete of someone who's not yet been stung by problems stemming from not using it!

Comment: Also, it's good to have a way to "hard reset" when you just want to start from scratch with a clean environment (and that would be `rm -rf /path/to/venv`)

Answer (score 1):

There are many benefit of working with virtual environment on your development machine.

- You can go to any version of any supported module to check for issues
- Your project runs under separate environment without conflicting with your system wide modules and settings
- Testing is easy
- Muliple version of same project can co-exist.

Answer (score 0):

if you develop multiple projects with different django versions, virtualenv is just a must thing, there is no other way (not that i know). you feel in heaven in virtualenv if you once experience the dependency hell. Even if you develop one project I would recommend to code inside virtualenv, you never know what comes next, back in the days, my old laptop was almost crashing because of so many dependency problems, after i discovered virtualenv, my old laptop became a brand new laptop for my eyes..

Answer (score 0):

No, in your case, you don't need to bother with virtualenv.  Since you're using a dedicated virtual machine it's just a layer of complexity you, as a noob, don't really need.

Virtualenv is pretty simple, in concept and usage, so you'll layer it on simply enough when the need arises. But, imho, there is added value in learning how a python installation is truly laid out before adding indirection.  When you hit a problem that it can solve, then go for it. But for now, keep it simple: don't bother.